# Is my openssl version vulnerable?

Tags: openssl, centos7, heartbleed-bug

I just installed Centos 7, with the default settings and i'd like to be sure if my openssl version is affected by heartbleed. I guess it's not, because the version command says `built on: Mon Dec 14 05:15:47 UTC 2015` and most of the vulnerable versions were built in 2013.

**Anyways, here is the command's full output:**

```
OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
built on: Mon Dec 14 05:15:47 UTC 2015
platform: linux-x86_64
options:  bn(64,64) md2(int) rc4(16x,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int) idea(int) blowfish(idx)
compiler: gcc -fPIC -DOPENSSL_PIC -DZLIB -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -DKRB5_MIT -m64 -DL_ENDIAN -DTERMIO -Wall -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic -Wa,--noexecstack -DPURIFY -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM
OPENSSLDIR: "/etc/pki/tls"
engines:  rdrand dynamic
```

Comment: `built on` does not matter, you can take sourcecode from the 1980s and build it today. What matters is `1.0.1e` and `11 Feb 2013`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://www.openssl.org/news/vulnerabilities.html

> CVE-2014-0160 (OpenSSL advisory) 7th April 2014:   A missing bounds
>   check in the handling of the TLS heartbeat extension can be used to
>   reveal up to 64kB of memory to a connected client or server (a.k.a.
>   Heartbleed). This issue did not affect versions of OpenSSL prior to
>   1.0.1. Reported by Neel Mehta. Fixed in OpenSSL 1.0.1g (Affected 1.0.1f, **1.0.1e**, 1.0.1d, 1.0.1c, 1.0.1b, 1.0.1a, 1.0.1)

Your version is `1.0.1e`, therefore it is vulnerable. Upgrade to at least `1.0.1g`.

Answer (score 0):

No - you are not vulnerable to heartbleed. The security fix was back-ported to the 1.0.1e package managed by centos.
See: https://wiki.centos.org/Security/Heartbleed